# How to get an ASP.NET Core MVC view to refer to a script section in another file?

Tags: c#, webpack, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm facing an issue when I'm trying to link my `.cshtml` file and my JavaScript reference in an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

As of right now, I have made a webpack setup such that it generates my JavaScript tags in a separate file called `home.sources.cshtml`:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="/js/npm.popperjs.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/npm.jquery.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/npm.bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/home.bundle.js"></script>
}
```

As you can see, my tags are encapsulated in the `Scripts` section. All these dependencies are for my `View/Home/Index.cshtml` page:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p class="test">Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

// Insert Script Section here
```

I want to make it so that the contents of `home.sources.cshtml` gets appended to this page at runtime. I don't want to manually add the script section myself, nor do I want to modify the page later on should I add more JavaScript dependencies. Any extra JavaScript dependencies that I add or remove will have their changes reflected only in `home.sources.cshtml`.

How do I go about doing that?

I was looking into `@Html.Partial()` in the attempt to add the `Script` section into the page as a partial view, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can create a layout that renders those scripts, then specify that `Index` uses that layout.  Or apply the layout globally to all pages, which is most common.

Comment: That's actually a neat idea. I managed to create a layout template that refers to my original layout, and injects JS tags. Then this file is used to generate a layout for every page, so that the user only needs to download the necessary JS bundles! And it works! Thank you! I'll post the solution I got shortly.

Comment: Great - glad to hear.  That's a very common paradigm in MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Jonespopolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786428/jonesopolis) for giving me this approach.

Essentially, what I need to do is to make a Layout template file, specifying that I am using my preexisting Layout file that I was already using, and declaring where all the JS tags would go. For instance, here's my template file:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

@RenderBody()

@section Scripts
{
    <% for (index in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js) { %>
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[index] %>"></script>
    <% } %>
}
```

This template file refers back to my original `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Head content here -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header content here -->

    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer content here -->
</footer>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The `@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)` line will render the Script section that I created in my template file.

From there, I used Webpack's Htmlwebpackplugin with the following config:

```
plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            template: 'Views/Shared/PageTemplate.cshtml',
            filename: '../../Views/Shared/home.sources.cshtml',
            minify: false
        }),
    ],
```

Running the `webpack` command will net us a `home.source.cshtml` file containing everything in the template file, but it shows my actual JS references needed for `home.cshtml`. All that's left is to make this file be the Layout for the page, by inserting this at the beginning:

```
@{
    Layout = "home.sources";
}
```

Running the application gives me the home page with all the correct JS tags downloaded! Now if I ever change my JS dependencies, I don't need to ever worry about generating the tags nor inserting them into the page, since all of that has been automated now, which is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

That's a very odd way to add script references if I understand what you're doing here.

Normally in MVC You see a couple lines in the layout page that look like this:

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Those refer to a set of bundles in App_Start -> BundleConfig.cs

That's the standard way of adding .js files to your runtime pages.

Comment: I should also add that you can render any text into a page from a string using @Html.Raw(string)

Comment: I actually never knew about this, since I am new to working with .NET MVC. The thing is that I'm getting my packages using npm, so I can make reference to them using ES6 import syntax. I'm not sure if this can be done using this system, plus BundleConfig.cs requires to me to insert statements to generate a bundle for each dependency, which is something that I just want to be automated. Hence I went with Webpack. It also allows me to compile TypeScript code if I ever need to do that in the future.

Comment: in mvc start pages i never see both them lines and the scripts is never like that it usually looks like this 
`@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)`

Answer (score 0):

I literally would do a partial, because it makes it look cleaner. So I have a partial called _ScriptsPartial and I have all js I need in it.

```html
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/srxbhbztd7jetvbg65d7si3gxatiku0ym7l8if3mda35vxxe/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
```

Then I use it as such in my layout like this I make many partials

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<partial name="_HeadPartial" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <partial name="_NavPartial" />
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <partial name="_Notification" />
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    <footer >
        <partial name="_FooterPartial" />
    </footer>

   <partial name="_ScriptsPartial" />

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Styles", required: false)
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
   
</body>
</html>
```

this seems to work okay :)